# How can I convert to length-1 arrays?

Tags: arrays, python-2.6, netcdf, scalar

I have opened a netCDF file that has two variables. Each variable has 4 dimensions:
time, height, latitude, and longitude.

I am using a script that is looping over every latitude(i) & longitude step(j) and delivers the data into a float format and are written into my output file, although I am getting this error:

```
utemp = float(uwind[i][i][j])  # data 
TypeError: only length-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars
```

Here I give you the coding I am using.

Read the length:

```
tstep = range(len(time))
lonstep = range(len(lon))
latstep = range(len(lat))
```

Set variables:

```
time = ncfile.variables['time']
lat = ncfile.variables['lat']
lon = ncfile.variables['lon'] 
uwind = ncfile.variables['10u']
```

Write into the file:

```
for t in tstep:
  for i in latstep:      
    for j in lonstep:      
      utemp = float(uwind[t][i][j])  
      windfile.write('%.4f '%utemp)
```

Can anybody help me convert the variable into the right format, without getting the error?

This is the change I made and it seems to write into the file just before it stops:

```
    for t in tstep:     

   windfile.write(header+'\n')    
   for hts in htstep:
      for i in latstep:     
         for j in lonstep:     
            utemp = float(uwind[hts][t][i][j])  # data 
            windfile.write('%.4f '%utemp)  
         windfile.write('\n')
   for hts in htstep:
      for i in latstep:
         for j in lonstep:
            vtemp = float(vwind[hts][t][i][j])
            windfile.write('%.4f '%vtemp)
         windfile.write('\n')
windfile.close()
```

From that I get

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "CFSR2SWAN.py", line 52, in <module>
    utemp = float(uwind[hts][t][i][j])  # data 
IndexError: index out of bounds
```

I would be grateful if someone could have a look

thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You say that `uwind` is defined at each lat, lon, height, and time, but you are only giving three indices when you call `uwind[i][i][j]`. So the output will be a 1-d array. Giving a 4th index, e.g. `uwind[i,i,j,j]` should resolve the error.

However, conceptually I'm not sure why you're using the `latstep` index `i` for both of the first two dimensions. If you're just trying to write the array to an external file, consider the [`pickle`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/pickle.html) (or `cPickle`) built-in library. (Looping over each gridpoint and time is extremely inefficient.)

Also, I'm assuming you're using the `netCDF4` module, in which case there is no need for the `float()` conversion -- the values will be floating point numbers already (which you can test with, e.g. `type(uwind[0,0,0,0]`).

Comment: I am quite new in python, added one more loop in reading the 3rd dimension of height, but now i get index out of bounds..

Comment: `netCDF4` usually orders the dimensions [time, height, lat, lon], but from the new code you posted you are indexing as if it was [height, time, lat lon]. Does replacing `uwind[hts][t][i][j]` with `uwind[t,hts,i,j]` solve the problem?

Comment: thank you very much it was a bit of a curious solution, but your last comment help me identify it, which i didn't knew it until now.

I will post the logic right under here so future question may be answered

Answer (score 0):

Just a sum of the comments and the solution found, Spencer Hill (in the comments) help me guide to the solution.

The problem was initially that not all of the dimensions were assigned to the `temp` value, each netCDF file has usually 3 or more dimensions (apart from the dataset included), in this case the 3 additional dimensions where time (t), height (ht) , latitude (lat), longitude (lon).

To see the data that are included in the netCDF one can either use `>ncdump -h fname` or `ncdsip` in Matlab, after some searching i found out that even though one can see the variables python's build in  netCDF modules open them in a different logic.

So after one has registered the data included in the file and identified them do in python

```
>>>shape(uwind)
```

and you will get something like this

```
(8737, 1, 5, 9)
```

While if you use ncdump or ncdisp the presentation of the variables dimension may differ.

so initially i had this line of code, due the fact that i was using ncdump to "open" the content of the file in Linux/UNIX

```
utemp = float(uwind[hts][t][i][j])
```

that produce the error mention.

When In python i tried to `>shape(varname)` i rewrote the temp as

```
 vtemp = float(vwind[t][hts][i][j])
```

And then the code was written correctly

I hope its gonna be helpful